# Formula to calculate the date a value will be reached

Tags: google-sheets, expression, forecasting, forecast

I have an array of dates and values and want to calculate in a formula at what date a certain value will be reached or be bigger.

Example:

```
1/1/2022 10
1/10/2022 13
1/20/2022 16
1/30/2022 19
```

At what date will 50 be reached?

GS has formulas to forecast the value for a date, but I know the value - I need the date.

Any help appriciated.

Comment: “GS has formulas to forecast the value for a date, but I know the value - I need the date.” So show us you using those formulas with your sample data you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

### 50 will be reached on 10th May 2022...

try `TREND` function:

```
=TREND(A1:A4; B1:B4; 50)
```

[image]

or `FORECAST`:

```
=FORECAST(50, A1:A4, B1:B4)
```

[image]

or `GROWTH`:

```
=GROWTH(A1:A4, B1:B4, 50)
```

[image]

or `LOGEST`, `LINEST` based on your specific project needs

Answer (score 0):

A4 is the first date a4:a7 is the dates, b4:b7 is the values, 365 is how many days I want to plot out into the future and 50 value is the number you requested to find the date.

```
=vlookup(50,arrayformula({Growth(B4:B7, A4:A7-$A$4, sequence(365)-1),sequence(365)+$A$4-1}),2)
```